# java reflection library which support to get nested object field values.

Tags: java, reflection

Is there knowing java reflection library which can get value of fields easily. 
Ex .
If I have Address Object inside User Object. And Address object have city attribute.

```
public class Address {
    private String city;
}

public class User {
    private String name;
    private Address address;
}
```

Then i want to pass address.city as parameter with User Object and i want to get city of user.

Is there any library which support my requirement.

Comment: It takes five minutes to write such a thing yourself…

Answer (score 6):

[Apache commons beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) has
`PropertyUtils.getNestedProperty(user, "address.city")`.

You can also do `PropertyUtils.setNestedProperty(user, "address.city", "new city")` but you need to make sure that address is not null.